# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. exception at string assignment

Tags: c#

This is  my code to generate an autogenerating jobcode and fill it in a text box

```
          public void newjobecodenoget(){
         String jobcodeno = null;
        OleDbConnection oleDbConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString);
        oleDbConnection1.Open();


        String query = "SELECT TOP 1 jobpk FROM jobcodemastertable ORDER BY jobpk DESC";
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);


        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        dAdapter.Fill(ds, "tbljobrdataview");
        Int32  S = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
        S++;

         jobcodeno = "NFT" + S.ToString();
         MessageBox.Show( jobcodeno);
         txtjobcode.Text = "NFT" + S.ToString();

    }
```

but Iam getting exception at the last line ie  txtjobcode.Text = "NFT" + S.ToString();
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
all other things are fine and jobcode is generated and shown in message box
can anyone help pls

my txtjobecode was declared as

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
         this.txtjobcode = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();  
// 
            // txtjobcode
            // 
            this.txtjobcode.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(98, 23);
            this.txtjobcode.Name = "txtjobcode";
            this.txtjobcode.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 20);
            this.txtjobcode.TabIndex = 0;
            //

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, `txtjobcode` is null. Since I do not see where `txtjobcode` is declared and assigned to, I cannot tell you why it is null.

Comment: Where is the code shown in your first example called? Is it possible that it is called before `InitializeComponent();`? `txtjobcode` will only have a value after `InitializeComponent` has been called. Note: `InitializeComponent` is called in the form constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Since clearly `S` is declared and has a value it follows that `txtjobcode` is `null`, hence you get this (fairly self-explanatory) exception. You have not shown where you declare or use  `txtjobcode` otherwise, but this is your problem.